# fetch Row value in pyspark list

Tags: pyspark

Using .collect method I have created my_list from pyspark df .

```
my_list[0] 
[Row(Specific Name/Path (to be updated)=u'Monitoring_file_hourely.csv')]
```

I want to extract value  Monitoring_file_hourely.csv

How this can be achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
my_list[0]['Specific Name/Path (to be updated)']
```